# Pivot a table rows to columns with no result

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a pivot table out of a temporary table (table1) with this columns:

```
student  percent_correct    exam_id     
student1       100                2
student1        93                3
student1        87                4
student2        93                2
student2        67                3
student2        67                4
student3       100                3
```

To get

```
student exam2 exam3 exam4
student1  100    93    87
student2  93     67    67
student3  -     100     -
```

After reading several  posts here I have used this code, and I get result cero, please read comments:

```
SET @sql_dynamic = (
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(exam_id = ''',
      exam_id,
      ''', percent_correct, 0)) AS exam',
      exam_id
    ))
FROM table1); #  MySQL returned 0 columns
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT student, ',@sql_dynamic,' FROM table1'); #  MySQL returned 0 columns

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; # MySQL returned 0 columns
EXECUTE stmt; #  MySQL returned 1 row
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; # MySQL returned 0 columns
```

I don't know how to get this table.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation

```
  select student,
         max(case when exam_id = 2 then percent_correct end) exam2,
         max(case when exam_id = 3 then percent_correct end) exam3,
         max(case when exam_id = 4 then percent_correct end) exam4
  from your_table
  group by student
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, there are dozens of exams and growing. That was just an example. The idea is to have a long term solution.